# Text user control with sorting possibility

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, user-controls, richtextbox

I need control in `winforms` that can add tens lines per second. I use now `richtextbox`, but i'm looking for something with sorting possibility (according some datatime or int)

Lines which are added are just custom objects complex of several int and datetime.

Delay aspect is quite important here.

**EDIT:**

It can be also some table/grid, but I suppose it take too much time (searching existing lines and inserting new line into appropriate place)

Answer (score 1):

`RichTextBox` will typically offer more overhead in managing, searching, and inserting.

Much more appropriate would be a control like `ListView`.  It gives simpler control over sorting, scrolling, and more.

Additionally, ListView has the ability to handle Virtual data backing.  If performance or content size is an issue, this will let you only worry about the sub-set currently displayed in the ListView "view" window.

Answer (score 0):

Two options
Use RichTextBox as you are doing now hold the data in a structure like SortedList from which the control will be updated.
Or, you can use a Grid, format the look and feel of the grid to remove the row & column grid lines and each new line will get appended this way you can let user sort by clicking on the header...

As for adding say ten lines per second I am pretty certain both these controls can handle more traffic than that....